# Makefile: can (GNU) make internally report whether a target needs updating?

Tags: makefile, target

This is my problem: I can build a binary in one of two ways and each has checks that can be done on them (under their own make targets); I would like a `check` target to run whichever target is appropriate dependent on which build target was run under a previous call of `make`: can this be done internally without touching files or some other "external" way of recording which build target was run?

An illustration may help:

```
.PHONY: all modified
all: $(obj)
    $(CXX) ... -o $(BIN)

modified: $(obj) $(extra_objs)
    $(CXX) ... -o $(BIN)


.PHONY: check check_all check_modified
check_all: all
    ...

check_modified: modified
    ...

check:
    # ??? Some makefile variable I don't know about?
```

so that I can ask this of the shell:

```
make X       # <-- X = {all, modified}
...          # <-- this is important: this is not a question of target dependency
make check   # <-- have `check' run `check_X' target
```

I figure that the only way for a particular `make` call to know which target was run before is by determining if it needs updating or not. Id est, if `all` is up-to-date, then run `check_all`, if `modified` is up-to-date then run `check_modified`, and default to `check_all`.

So, can I ask `make` "internally" whether target X would be updated if I asked to run it? "Internal" meaning no calling of `$(MAKE) -n`, or no `touch Y` and then asking the shell `if [ -f Y ] ...`.

As you can see, it's not quite a question of dependency because that, clearly, will build the dependency when all I want to do is check to see whether it has been run before. So, any ideas or (alternative suggestions)?

UPDATE:

OK, I guess the answer is: No. The best I can probably do is this:

```
.PHONY: check
check: $(if $(wildcard $(firstword $(extra_objs))),check_modified,check_all)
```

Obviously, this method is functionally the same as creating a file when creating one of the targets and then checking for that, but in this case the file I'm checking for is created anyway and unique to the target that creates it, which I suppose makes it slightly less ugly.

(Note: I ran into the problem that:

```
.PHONY: check
check:
    $(MAKE) -q modified && $(MAKE) check_modified || $(MAKE) check_all
```

won't exactly work for the code I had above because `all` and `modified` are phony and so will always need updating as far as `make` is concerned, so that kind of rules that one out! But, it's a simple and concise way of solving the problem for targets named after the file they'd create so I'll mention it for reference.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could record the build type in a file and read that back later to pick the right "check" target like so:

```
all: $(obj)
    $(CXX) ... -o $(BIN)
    echo $@ > $(BIN)-kind

modified: $(obj) $(extra_objs)
    $(CXX) ... -o $(BIN)
    echo $@ > $(BIN)-kind

check: $(if $(wildcard $(BIN)-kind),check_$(shell cat $(BIN)-kind))
```

Comment: Well, that's much nicer than shell scripting in the target recipe! Interestingly, replacing `$(BIN)-kind` with `$(MAKE) -q all` in `$(wildcard...)` also does the same thing (for what I need it to do) and doesn't rely on the existence of an external file. By the looks of it (on my system) `$(wildcard $(MAKE) -q all)` evaluates to `"all"` if `$(MAKE) -q all` returns zero, and evaluates to an empty string otherwise. But, I can't find documentation for this behaviour in the GNU make manual: is it undefined?

Comment: `$(wildcard $(MAKE) -q all)` evaluates to those, if any, of "make", "-q", and "all" which are files in the current directory. If that gives you correct behaviour, that's a hell of a coincidence :-)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't count on that being reliably useful! I forget exactly which target I specified in the Makefile I had, but I guess it must have been a non-phony one...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe spawning another make internally with the -q flag helps?

> Usage: make [options] [target] ...
>
> Options:
>
> [...]
>
> -q, --question              Run no
>   commands; exit status says if up to
>   date.

Comment: Ah, didn't spot that flag: much simpler than my suggestions above! Still, though, it'd be nice if I didn't have to call `make` from inside the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title of your question, see [double colon rules.](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Double_002dColon) Quoting the manual:

> Double-colon rules are somewhat obscure and not often very useful; they provide a mechanism for cases in which the method used to update a target differs depending on which prerequisite files caused the update, and such cases are rare.

Sounds (almost) just what you are after.

Comment: It doesn't help that the manual calls the feature obscure! OK, a bit of googling seems to suggest that a double-colon rule won't exactly help me. Basically, it seems that it would only allow me to update the double-colon'd target depending on what prerequisite was updated, which is just what the manual says. So, a double-colon'd `check` would run all its dependencies at first (which I don't want to do) and since it is phony would always do this (which only exasperates the situation).